# Accessing transparent identifier in select throws it is not referenced from scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, .net-core

Accessing transparent identifier in select throwing exception.

```
var result = (from t1 in table1
              join t2 in table2 on t1.col1 equals t2.col1 into myTable1
              from a in myTable1.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join t3 in table3 on t1.col2 equals t3.col2 into myTable2
              from b in myTable2.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where t1.col1 == 1
              select new
              {
                   prop1 = b,
                   prop2 = myTable1,
                   prop3 = myTable1.Count()
              });
```

Exception:

`variable 'myTable1' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined.`

Comment: does it work if you select specific *values* from `myTable1`?

Comment: use a not myTable1

Comment: If your temp table works same as in SQL side run code, temp tables are only available for the scope of the code (one connection, if you disconnect, temp table disappears.  you can use a stage table (permeant table you clear out after every use) then the table will exist if you close/open connections (but if used my multiple processes you would have to do more advanced so the different processes do not overlap.

Comment: note: `myTable1` isn't a "temp table" - I *think* the correct term here is "transparent identifier"; it only exists as a label for the purposes of constructing the LINQ expression; if you do something like `prop2 = new { myTable1.Foo, myTable1.Bar }`, it may well work

Comment: Thank you for the correct term @MarcGravell, I've updated the question. I've tried the way you've mentioned  like this `prop2 = new { myTable1.Foo, myTable1.Bar }`. No luck, getting a compile time error.

 ````IEnumerable<Table> does not contain a definition for 'Property' and no accessible extension method 'property' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Table>' could be found. CS1061.````

Comment: It's not clear what you want and without the bounty this question would get closed as "Needs details or clarity". If you want a Count of `myTable1` you have to remove the `from a in myTable1.DefaultIfEmpty()` part, because it flattens the implicit `GroupJoin`. If you want `myTable1` properties you have to use `a` just as you use `b`. You can't have both the count and properties in one scope. If you want the bounty to pay off then you need to clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Need to create a class with your result.

Please check the following way.

```
PropModel propModel = new PropModel();

            propModel  = (from t1 in table1
                          join t2 in table2 on t1.col1 equals t2.col1 into myTable1
                          from a in myTable1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          join t3 in table3 on t1.col2 equals t3.col2 into myTable2
                          from b in myTable2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          where t1.col1 == 1
                          select new
                          {
                              prop1 = b,
                              prop2 = myTable1.FirstOrDefault(),
                              prop3 = myTable1.Count()
                          }).FirstOrDefault();

public class PropModel
            {
                public table3 prop1 { get; set; }
                public table2 prop2 { get; set; }
                public Int32 prop3 { get; set; }
            }
```